# Pass a reference to std::ifstream as parameter

Tags: c++, function, ifstream

I'm trying to write a function with an `ifstream&` argument.

```
void word_transform(ifstream & infile)
{
    infile("content.txt");
    //etc
}
```

which gave me an error:

> Type 'ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream ') does not provide a call operator.

Can you please me what's wrong?

Comment: `infile.open("content.txt");` presumably.

Comment: Functions that take stream arguments usually work with a stream that is already open. For example, `ifstream s("content.txt"); word_transform(s);`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*call operator* is a function like `operator()( params )` allowing to use the syntax `myObject( params )`.

So, when you write `infile(...)`, you are trying to us a call operator.

What you are trying to do is to open a file, use the `open` method:

```
void word_transform(ifstream & infile)
{
    infile.open("content.txt",std::ios_base::in);
    if ( infile.is_open() )
        infile << "hello";
    infile.close();
}
```

But, as commented, it does not really make sense to pass infile reference to such a function. You may consider:

```
void word_transform(istream& infile)
{
    infile << "hello";
}

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("content.txt",std::ios_base::in);
    if ( infile.is_open() )
        word_transform( infile );
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
void word_transform()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("content.txt",std::ios_base::in);
    if ( infile.is_open() )
        infile << "hello";
    infile.close();
}

int main()
{
    word_transform();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your last comment is very pertinent: if he is going to open and close the file in the function, the `std::ifstream` should be local to the function; it serves no purpose to have it as an argument.  A more frequent idiom, however, would be to have it opened and closed by the caller, and to pass a `std::istream&` argument (rather than an `std::ifstream&`).

Answer (score 3):

You attempt to call `operator()` on your parameter. That will not work. Are you trying to open a file? If you get an `ifstream` as parameter, it should be open from the start because you opened it outside your function. Passing a stream and then opening it inside your function does not make sense.

```
void word_transform(std::ifstream& infile)
{
    // read something from infile
}

int main()
{
   std::ifstream file("content.txt");

   // error checks

   word_transform(file);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
infile("content.txt");
```

Note that this would try to call operator() on already created object of type infile. As no such operator exists from ifstream , you got an error.

Rather you should do:-

```
infile.open("content.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the call operator is `operator()`, which apparently is not defined for `ifstream`. You have to do something different with the argument of `word_transform`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, (references to) streams are passed to functions for I/O. This means the function should take
`std::istream` or `std::ostream` argument, but not `std::ifstream` or `std::ofstream`. This way your function can be used with any stream object derived from `std::istream`, including `std::cin`, `std::istrstream`, and `std::ifstream`.

As nvoigt said, passing an `std::ifstream` to a function for opening makes little sense. It is definitely not clear to the caller that its stream may be closed and opened to another file.